Paste event not working on second time in jquery
HTML:
<div class="textarea" id="text"></div>

I have tried using below code but first time event is triggered. when i paste it second time event is not triggered
$("div.texarea").on('paste', function (e) {
  var text = (e.originalEvent) || e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');      
  document.execCommand('inserttext', false,text);
});


That looks like it should work, please include a [mre] of the problem.

You have a typo in the selector

As mentioned above, you have texarea rather than textarea in your JS, but if it's working once that's probably an issue with the question rather than the original code. (Your HTML is also missing a slash in the closing tag) If possible, please put together a snippet that displays the exact problem you want to solve.
